# Git installer for Mac: Why is /usr/local/git/bin in my PATH?

Tags: git, macos, bash, path

I recently installed the latest version of git (1.7.6) for OS X (10.7).

When I run `echo $PATH`, it returns this:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

What I'm curious about is why/how `/usr/local/git/bin` is there. It's not in any of the usual places, like .bash_profile or .profile.

Where does the OS X installer add this to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look for `MacOS.plist` or look in: `/etc/paths.d`.

Comment: Where is MacOS.plist located? I can't find it, not even with `find / -name MacOS.plist`. Is it deprecated? (But +1 for `/etc/paths.d/`)

Comment: I's not deprecated, but you need to create it yourself if you awnt to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Its added in your .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:"${PATH}"
```